# what can you do when window.location.href returns null

Tags: javascript

window.location.href returns null. Is there another way to get the current window url that is more solid and will work everytime?

Comment: Wouldn't that only happen if you're not using a Web Browser or you set it like that. What are you getting at? `location` by itself will get the URL easier, but that should work too.

Comment: Please describe what you're doing that it would return `null`. Are you building a web worker or something?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What happens when you do `delete window.location.href` and then read its value again?

Comment: I am really curious as to how you are getting null

Comment: The only way I think this could happen is if the current window doesn't have a URL, because it was created with `window.open()` with no URL.

Comment: So asking how to get the current window url is meaningless, because there's nothing to get.

Answer (score 4):

You have not provided us with enough information about the environment in which your code is running for us to provide good alternatives for you.  You have stated that [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) is returning `null`. You could try [other properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) of [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) (which returns a [location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)). Other answers have provided a variety of combinations of the properties of that object which might be reasonable.

However, if `window.location.href` is returning `null`, then the other properties of `window.location` will probably also not provide valid information.

One alternative you could try is [`document.documentURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentURI):

```
var theURL = document.documentURI;
```

[MDN makes this comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentURI) with respect to `document.documentURI`:

> HTML documents have a [`document.URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/URL) property which returns the same value. Unlike URL, documentURI is available on all types of documents.

As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) has mentioned in a comment, and depending on the browser you are using, the issue might be that there just is not a URI associated with the `<window>` or `<document>`. In which case, it may be that *none* of your available options will provide you with a valid URI. If we knew more about the environment in which your code is running, we might be able to provide you with good alternatives, or actually answer what to do (or what it means), when you get `null` or invalid information for the various ways of obtaining the current URI.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
var URLstring = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
var URL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
```

or use jQuery to get it:

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: You can also use this: `var URL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
`

Comment: OP doesn't say anything about jQuery, I suggest making the comment the actual post

Comment: Ok, let me do that.

Comment: If `window.location.href` isn't set, where will jQuery get the attribute from?

Comment: @Barmar, it think the jQuery won't have a value if `window.location.href` is not set, so I think that the `var URL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;` is the best answer.

Comment: If `window.location.href` isn't set, I suspect neither will any of the other `window.location` properties.

Comment: They call come from the same place in the browser.

Comment: I don't think because the href property is not set does mean all the other properties of `window.location` are not set unless investigated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121214/discussion-between-d3r1ck-and-barmar).